# How to delete Magento Dataflow Import uploaded files?

Tags: magento

I am having a terrible time trying to locate the files that are populating a select drop down in the "Import All Products" dataflow profile in Magento. Inside of the "Run Profile" tab there is a Select Dropdown that contains all of the files I have ever uploaded. I want to remove these as I have already uploaded about 15 `.csv` files.

I have tried searching in PHPMyAdmin for the file name. Also have tried `sudo locate import-20140320221637-1_export_all_products.csv` and `sudo grep "import-20140320221637-1_export_all_products.csv" /var/www/` but I come up with empty results. Where are these being stored at?

Answer (score 2):

Check in your `magento_root/var/import` folder. This is where usually all the import csv files are stored.

Comment: I wish it were that simple but there was only one file there. Not any of the files listed in the drop down though. I am beginning to wonder if maybe they save them with a preceding dot to hide them? I might check that later

Comment: @Yamaha32088 hi, which version of magento are you using?

Comment: In magento 1.7.0.2 the csv files are located in var/importexport foleder. Can you check this folder too?

Comment: 1.8 I also checked in that folder to no avail.

Comment: well when i tested it, the csv files are coming in the above folder i mentioned. Are you able to upload the products or are you getting any errors?